# Is it possible to make the text in terminal invisible?

Tags: command-line

I would like to know to make the text in terminal invisible. That's it just to make it invisible, not to change it's color to hide it with the back ground, but completely invisible. Thanks

Comment: any particular requirement?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: Is this a troll question? Can you please explain why you'd like to do so, as to give us the motivation to help you?

Comment: well... I believe his question is easily answered :+) And I disagree with the downvote so here is an upvote ;)

Comment: Oh right well i want it to be invisible so no one can see my code in terminal, that's it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a terminal you can turn the echo off with `stty -echo`

Example:

```
echo "enter password"
stty -echo
read password
stty echo
echo $password
```

Comment: Thank you! So if i want it to appear again what would i need to type in? And how can i make the john@john:~$ invisible aswell? Thanks! :D

Comment: Making it visible again is the `stty echo` part ;) You can not hide the prompt but can change it to a single char. Search for PS1  and  you will find several examples ;)